# (store procedure) combine result 2 rows into 1 row result

Tags: sql, stored-procedures

can i combine result **row 3 and row 4** into 1 row record?

```
select @fYear as [Year],
    (case when main.Description in ('Kecil', 'Tanah') then 'JK'
         else main.Description
    end) as description,

    --CardType,
    sum(case when MONTH(blue.AppliedDate) = 1 then 1 else 0 end) as Jan_Collection,
    sum(case when MONTH(blue.AppliedDate) = 2 then 1 else 0 end) as Feb_Collection,
    ...

    from tblR as main
    left join tblP as b on  main.requestorid = b.requestorid
    left join tblB as blue on b.partyid = blue.partyid and YEAR(blue.AppliedDate) = @fYear

    group by  (case when main.Description in ('Kecil', 'Tanah') then 'JK'
           else main.Description
      end)
```

this output like:
https://gyazo.com/d930cb2aee92f90ba31dd543d6ca64f3

but can i display combine record row 3 and 4 into 1 record like JK like this picture: https://gyazo.com/a89ed2fa04b51135bf8601d59d4af0b2

Thanks.

Comment: there's no logic behind that grouping. Or I can't see it at least

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to combine those specific `descriptions`, you can use a `case`, both in the `select` and the `group by`:

```
select @fYear as [Year],
       (case when description in ('kecil', 'Tanah') then 'JK'
             else main.Description
        end) as Description,
       sum(case when MONTH(blue.AppliedDate) = 1 then 1 else 0 end) as Jan_Collection,
       sum(case when MONTH(blue.AppliedDate) = 2 then 1 else 0 end) as Feb_Collection,
       ...
from tblR main left join
     tblP b
     on  main.requestorid = b.requestorid left join
     tblB
     blue
     on b.partyid = blue.partyid and YEAR(blue.AppliedDate) = @fYear
group by (case when description in ('kecil', 'Tanah') then 'JK'
               else main.Description
          end)
```

Comment: how to order by Berhad, Tinggi, JK?  because i add 
`order by (case main.Description  when 'Berhad' then 1
when  'Tinggi' then 2
when  'JK' then 3
ELSE description END) ASC`